# Best way to implement no-password sign-in with Firebase

Tags: javascript, web-applications, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'd like to simplify the authentication workflow in my Firebase app, and let users connect without password:

- With third party OAuth providers: Facebook, Google, etc.

or

- With email

If the later, the user would just fill in their address, receive a URL, and instantly get logged in without having to type/remember a password.

Whenever they logout, or, their session times out, they would enter their email again, and receive a new link to start a new session.

**How to do that with Firebase?**

I feel like it's not possible on the client, so what would be the best server side routine to achieve that workflow?

Comment: Have you considered using a customPassword e.g timStamp(or maybe mixed with random alphabets.. or whateva ) from your front end? And for session expiration you can use that timestamp to know when session started.

Comment: Ok but how to log them using a link in the email? The more important is not about the time or timeout, but the process of loging in with a link sent by email. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Well i think you can send a verification email, and change the text of verification email to your needs.

Comment: Good idea. Can I send another one for re-login?

Comment: Yea whenever your session expire's  send a verification email again..Et Voila.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that. Feel free to answer the question with code, or i'll do that after I implement and test that solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, after taking some time to figure this out, I quickly realised that the email verification process cannot be used to solve this: the function to get this email sent can only be called by *already logged-in users* (which makes perfect sense). Hence it cannot be used to sign-in.

---

**I ended up using this workflow with Firebase custom authentication :**

1. `CLIENT` User asks to login, he's asked his email address, and told he will receive a link to complete log in upon form submission.
2. `SERVER` Receives the email address. Finds or creates user id belonging to that user, [creates a custom token with this uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and sends an authenticated link by email (for example: `http://myapp.com/?token=XYZ`)
3. `CLIENT` User comes back in the app by clicking on that link, and the app can use the `token` parameter to [immediately log-in the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) using `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`.

**Look, ma, no passwud!**

Comment: I've checked at the docs that [custom tokens expire after one hour](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

Comment: Firebase auth now supports passwordless email link sign-in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth

Answer (score 2):

For **Email** part you can :-

- Use custom passwords from Front-End eg:- timestamp's or some random words+timeStamp . And store that timeStamp in the users's Database for future reference for session expiration.
- For sending a link for starting a session you can use the verification email to send a link inside and modulate the contents of the mail as per your needs.
- For knowing when your session expire's:-

  - Just retrieve the **timeStamp** lets say that is `timeKeyRetrieved`
  - Check how much time has passed since the **timeStamp**

**PS:-** For checking wether user session has expired during the user is online. You will have to use timer. And whenever your users gets online just retrieve the **timeStamp** in ***AppDelegate*** methods or ***viewWillAppear:***

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I was using the web SDK (javascript) ^^